# alternative for loop in data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am facing a problem with the amount of time needed to run my code. Basically, I have several columns a key value in the last column (that I identify as the mean in the reproducible example).  I want it to be 1 when it is below the value and 2 when it is above.

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
a <- c(1,3,5,6,4)
b <- c(10,4,24,5,3)
df <- data.frame (a,b)
df$mean <- rowMeans (df)

for (i in 1:5){
df[i,1:2] [df[i,1:2]<df$mean[i]] <- 1
df[i,1:2] [df[i,1:2]>df$mean[i]] <- 2
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do,

```
df[1:2] <- (df[1:2] > df$mean) + 1 #removed as.integer as per @akrun's comment
```

Which gives,

> ```
>   a b mean
> 1 1 2  5.5
> 2 1 2  3.5
> 3 1 2 14.5
> 4 2 1  5.5
> 5 2 1  3.5
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Always avoid using loops when possible in R!

Alternative Solution using mutate_each from dplyr

```
df %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(mean>.,1,2)), 1:2)
```

Also gives

```
  a b mean
1 1 2  5.5
2 1 2  3.5
3 1 2 14.5
4 2 1  5.5
5 2 1  3.5
```